# Jinja2: Converting hex to Base64

Tags: python, jinja2

Is this possible?

Say I have a hex value `32ABE23`, is there a filter to show it as Base64?
Well I saw that there is | `b64encode` filter.

I trried following with no success

```
{{ 32ABE23 | string() | b64encode }}
```

I get

```
TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'b64encode'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own filters in Jinja2:

```
import base64
def b64encode(s):
    return base64.b64encode(s)

jinja2_environment.filters['b64encode'] = b64encode
```

Of course this can be simplified as:

```
import base64
jinja2_environment.filters['b64encode'] = base64.b64encode
```

Comment: In Flash, that code works by putting @app.template_filter('b64encode')